# Find values in string between underscores?

Tags: php

I have values stored in a database that look like this

```
10_wc_asis
```

I need to isolate the values between the underscores (_) like this:

```
Value 1 = 10
Value 2 = wc
Value 3 = asis
```

How can I do that in PHP?

Comment: `explode('_', '10_wc_asis')`

Answer (score 0):

Try [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) :

```
$str = "10_wc_asis";
$pieces = explode("_", $str);
var_dump($pieces)
```